# Bash prompt shortening

Tags: bash

I've just moved from `tcsh` to `bash` and I particular missed the directory-shortening prompt options using `%c02` (with `ellipsis` also set).

I see that `PROMPT_DIRTRIM` does almost the right thing (except ellipsis, I think) but I'm only on `bash` 3 (on OS X). I found [this recipe elsewhere on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1618602/12266), which shortens on total length, so breaks pathnames in the middle of directories, which I didn't like.

So I came up with this:

```
PROMPT_DIRTRIM=2   ## from bash4, but used here
dirtrim() 
{
    local NAME="$1" start= endelts=
    [[ "$NAME" =~ ^"$HOME"(/|$) ]] && NAME="~${NAME#$HOME}"  ## $HOME ==> ~
    IFS=/ read -ra elts <<< "$NAME";          ## split $PWD on "/"
    start=$((${#elts[@]}-${PROMPT_DIRTRIM}))  ## first element to retain
    if [ ${start} -gt 1 ]; then     
        for ((i=${start}; i<${#elts[@]}; i++)); do 
            endelts="${endelts}/${elts[$i]}"; ## concat together the trailing path
        done
        NAME="...${endelts}"
    fi
    echo "$NAME"    
}
PS1='\h:$(dirtrim "$PWD")\$ '
```

It works:

```
blackat:~$ cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/Apple
blackat:.../Application Support/Apple$
```

But I'm newish to `bash` and unhappy with the explicit `for (())` loop; however, I couldn't seem to find any other way to rejoin the last entries of the split `elts` array in a way that deals correctly with spaces in dir names (e.g., using `${elts[@]:${start}}`). Any hints to do that or other improvements?

(By the way, I think this *is* a programming question, to the extent that `bash` is a programming language....)

Comment: Bash is a programming language.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Agreed -- that was in response to two votes to close!

Comment: And I'm affirming that questions about Bash programming are programming questions and are therefore on-topic at Stack Overflow.  Closing questions about shell programming as off-topic used to be a major problem; these days, I don't see it happening as much, but that may simply mean I'm missing it and it happens all the time.  FWIW: I don't like long prompts either: I don't include the path in the prompt at all.  On a machine 'sphinx', my prompt is `Sphinx JL: `.  With the Mac terminal, you can have the path in the terminal title bar (Properties -> Window and look for Title section).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

```
if ((start > 1)); then
  name=$(IFS=/; echo .../"${elts[*]:start}")
  # If your terminal is correctly set up for unicode, you can save two character positions:
  # name=$(IFS=/; echo …/"${elts[*]:start}")
fi
```

Note that in bash, in an arithmetic context, which includes the inside of `((...))` and array subscripts, you can write just the name of the variable; no need for sigils.

Another way to do it would be

```
if ((start > 1)); then
  printf -v name "/%s" "${elts[@]:start}"
  name=...$name
fi
```

Yet another solution, using regex captures in the `BASH_REMATCH` array rather than splitting and rejoining the string:

```
dirtrim () { 
  local path="$1";
  [[ $path =~ ^"$HOME"(/.*)? ]] && path=~${BASH_REMATCH[1]};
  ((PROMPT_DIRTRIM)) &&
    [[ $path =~ ...*((/[^/]*){$PROMPT_DIRTRIM}) ]] &&
    path=…${BASH_REMATCH[1]};
  echo "$path"
}
```

The `((PROMPT_DIRTRIM))` test is not completely robust because of the peculiarities of bash evaluation in an arithmetic context. For distribution you might prefer something like `[[ $PROMPT_DIRTRIM =~ ^[1-9][0-9]*$ ]]`

Comment: 1. Agreed about casing; I got `NAMES` from [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1618602/12266). 2. I did mean `((start>1))` -- if `start==1` you just keep the first entry; 3. I think *you* meant `name=$(IFS=/; echo .../"${elts[*]:start}")` (nb. `IFS=/` and missing `$`)

Comment: @andrew: The first entry of a bash array has index 0. You're right about the typos, I was rushing out the door when I typed that. Sorry, and I fixed it now.

Comment: yes, but the zeroth entry is "~" or null, so we do really want to shorten only when `start>1`

Comment: @AndrewJaffe: Ah, good point. No reason to shorten if it's not going to be shorter. For your viewing pleasure, I added a solution using regex which avoids the split and join altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but you might want to to look at how `mksh` accomplishes this:

```
PS1=${| local e=$? (( e )) && REPLY+="$e|" REPLY+=${USER:=$(ulimit -c 0; id -un 2>/dev/null || echo \?)} REPLY+=@${HOSTNAME%%.*}: local d=${PWD:-?} p=~; [[ $p = ?(*/) ]] || d=${d/#$p/~} local m=${%d} n p=...; (( m > 0 )) || m=${#d} (( m > (n = (COLUMNS/3 < 7 ? 7 : COLUMNS/3)) )) && d=${d:(-n)} || p= REPLY+=$p$d return $e }
```

Unfortunately, it uses some extensions that are not in `bash`, I believe.

Aso, since you're switching shells... have you considered [fish](http://fishshell.com)?

It does this out-of-the-box, and then some.